# How to use where with Laravel Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel-5

I am attempting to

```
 $orders = \App\Order::with(['Customer'])->where('customers.first', 'LIKE', "{$filterFirst}%");
```

However, I am getting

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customers.first' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `orders` where `customers`.`first` LIKE %)
```

How can I use `where` as well as `with`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot filter out related model just by eager loading, 
the right approach is following way.

```
  $orders = \App\Order::whereHas('Customer', function ($query) {
     $query->where('customers.first', 'like', "{$filterFirst}%");
})->get();
```